# Can we avoid npe while checking for null in nested java objects?

Tags: java, pointers, null, object, nested

1) `if(null != parentObj.childObj)`

2) `if(parentObj.childObj != null)`

Do you think that "1" will avoid a potential null pointer exception in the case where 'parentObj' is null, in contrast to "2"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

If parentObj is null then any attempt to call a method or reference a field will result in a NullPointerExcepton. != always evaluates both sides.

Just check if parentObj is null first and handle it appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just `if(parentObj != null && parentObj.childObj != null)` ?

Comment: That's what the OP is asking.  He's looking to avoid the wordiness of the check.

Comment: @Tony Ennis.  1) That's not how I read the question. 2) Anyway, the answer is that he can't, and @irrelephant's answer provides him with the sanest alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If parentObj is null, referencing any method/field on parentObj will result in an NPE. In other words, you need `if (parentObj != null && parentObj.childObj != null)` to avoid an NPE. Groovy cuts down on this (very common) type of verbosity with the [safe navigation operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SafeNavigationOperator%28%3F.%29), which lets you write `if (parentObj?.childObj)`.

Comment: At one point, the safe navigation operator or something similar might have made it into Java 7 via project Coin.  But it didn't make the cut; see http://blogs.sun.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_final_five